# Conditional Comments Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, conditional-comments

Are there specific [Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx) available for older versions of Firefox? (eg 3.0)

Answer (score 11):

No, they are only supported by IE.

There are CSS hacks though. See: http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/06/28/css-hacks-for-different-versions-of-firefox/

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but it would also involve Javascript, plus I would like to keep my style sheets "hack" free.

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge. As far as I know, conditional comments are an Internet Explorer-only feature.

[QuirksMode.org agrees](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: Thanks, maybe a little more specific:

I am trying to create a solid fallback for @font-face by initiating Cufón for older browsers. Conditional comments came to mind but perhaps there is another route?

Comment: Can't you do that with font-family? Put your font-face first on the list, then your fallbacks in sequence after that. If the browser can handle font-face, it'll use that. If it can't handle font-face, it'll default to Cufón (and if the user doesn't have Cufón, it'll default to the next in line, etc.)

Comment: Cufón is a text-replacement engine with the Canvas element. An ugly solution if there ever was one. http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Comment: Ok, I didn't check so I was assuming Cufón was a font. This complicates things a bit. I suppose your best option might be to write some javascript to determine what browser/version combo the user is using, and go from there. Not the most elegant solution, but not the ugliest I've ever seen either.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a solid fallback
>   for @font-face by initiating Cufón for
>   older browsers. Conditional comments
>   came to mind but perhaps there is
>   another route?

You just have to inject the cufón script tags [conditionally](http://github.com/Mouvedia/lack-of-font-face-support-detection).

Answer (score -1):

Received an email from **Faruk Ates** the developer of [Modernizr][1]

[1]: http://www.modernizr.com/ confirming that **it** will do the trick.... and more:-)