# Conditional comments for Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any equivalent to IE conditional comment for chrome and safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052218/is-there-any-equivalent-to-ie-conditional-comment-for-chrome-and-safari)

To target IE 8

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
add IE 8 specific code (JS/HTML/CSS)
<![endif]-->
```

Can found similar kind of solution for Firefox ?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: It might be better to address what specific question/problem you have. The reason for IE conditional comments is because IE is so severely busted and difficult to update, Firefox is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any equivalent to IE conditional comment for chrome and safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052218/is-there-any-equivalent-to-ie-conditional-comment-for-chrome-and-safari) or perhaps [Conditional Comments Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041870/conditional-comments-firefox)

Comment: you can check which browser you are using through javascript make condition for it and add specific `js` and `css` file

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Conditional Comments:

1. IE (Any version of IE)
2. lt IE version (Versions less than version)
3. lte IE version(Versions less than or equal to version)
4. IE version (Only version)
5. gte IE version (Versions greater than or equal to version)
6. gt IE version (Versions greater than version)
7. IE - Internet Explorer
8. ! Opera = not opera
9. Gecko - Gecko based browsers (Firefox, Camino etc)
10. Webkit - Webkit based browsers (Safari, Chrome, Shiira etc)
11. SafMob - Mobile Safari (iPhone / iPod Touch)
12. Opera - Opera's browser
13. IEMac - Internet Explorer for the Mac
14. Konq - Konqueror
15. IEmob - IE mobile
16. PSP - Playstation Portable
17. NetF - Net Front

Answer (score -2):

There are no conditional comments for Firefox. If you want that, you must use JavaScript.

**EDIT**

There aren't conditional tags in Firefox, if you want to do something for a specific browser, you must use JavaScript.

Comment: There aren't conditional tags in Firefox, if you want that, you must use JavaScript. What is it that is out of context?

Comment: Ok, bad english in first answer, sorry. Why do you need conditional tags?